# Python: how to make conditional operation in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an  `numpy` array `M` of dimension `NxM` and a dataframe `tmp` containing the information of the cell of the array.

If I have to add values to the cell of `M`, I do

```
M[tmp.a, tmp.b] = tmp1.n
```

However I would like to add the values only to those cells in which `M < tmp.n`, something like

```
M[M[tmp.a, tmp.b] < tmp1.n] = tmp1.n
```

I solved in this way

```
s = shape(M)
M0 = np.zeros((s[1], s[0]))
M0[tmp1.a, tmp1.b] += tmp1.n
idx = np.where(M < M0)
M[idx[:][0], idx[:][1]] = M0[idx[:][0], idx[:][1]]
```

Comment: `M[tmp.a, tmp.b]` is not valid Python. Or is `M` not a Python `list`? What is it?

Comment: Yes it works with my me

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank it is valid

Comment: Nope. If this is Numpy, the question should mention it.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank I thought that if I say it is an array, automatically it is a numpy. Btw I tried to solve it.

Comment: python array != numpy array

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you may do something like:

```
M[tmp.a, tmp.b] = max(tmp1.n, M[tmp.a, tmp.b])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [Numpy logical indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html)

```
# a logical (boolean) array
log = M < tmp.n

# apply it to source and target and use `+=` to add the values
M[log] += tmp.n[log]
```

If the arrays don't have the same shape then you can also pick a specific dimension:

```
log = M[:, 0] < tmp.n

# apply it to source and target and use `+=` to add the values
M[log, 0] += tmp.n[log]
```